# Задачка на булеву алгебру, которую решил неправильно C++

Tags: c++, булева-алгебра

Задачка:

[image: Задачка]

Решил сделать перебором:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool func(bool x, bool y, bool z, bool w)
{
    return (!y + z + !x * w) == (w == z);
}

int main()
{
    cout << "x" << " " << "y" << " " << "z" << " " << "w" << " " << "F" << endl;
    for (size_t x = 0; x < 2; x++)
    {
        for (size_t y = 0; y < 2; y++)
        {
            for (size_t z = 0; z < 2; z++)
            {
                for (size_t w = 0; w < 2; w++)
                {
                    if (func(x, y, z, w) == 1)
                    {
                        cout << x << " " << y << " " << z << " " << w << " " << "1" << endl;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Вывод программы:

```
x y z w F
0 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 0 1
1 1 0 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
```

Немного изменю код программы, чтобы столбцы вывода стали совпадать со столбцами условия.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool func(bool x, bool y, bool z, bool w)
{
    return (!y + z + !x * w) == (w == z);
}

int main()
{
    cout << "w" << " " << "y" << " " << "z" << " " << "x" << " " << "F" << endl; //<=== поменял местами x и w
    for (size_t x = 0; x < 2; x++)
    {
        for (size_t y = 0; y < 2; y++)
        {
            for (size_t z = 0; z < 2; z++)
            {
                for (size_t w = 0; w < 2; w++)
                {
                    if (func(x, y, z, w) == 1)
                    {
                        cout << w << " " << y << " " << z << " " << x << " " << "1" << endl; //<=== поменял местами x и w
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Вывод программы:

```
w y z x F
0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 1 1
1 1 0 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
```

Таблица из условия:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Итого видим, что вторая строчка вывода программы равна второй строчке таблицы условия. Но в таблице условия есть первая и третья строчка, а ей может соответствовать только ОДНА строчка из вывода программы (третья). В чем проблема? Моя программа генерирует не все возможные комбинации?

Comment: А у нее точно есть решение? а то я набросал, но что-то не получается. Пустые места трактовать же так, что при любых значениях на этих местах выражение F остается тем же?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первая строка глубоко противоречива :) - 1 должна получаться при наборах 0100 и 1100.

Первый набор непосредственной подстановкой одной переменной 1 и остальных 0 дает, что это x обязан быть 1. Итак, вторую букву мы определили.

Теперь, подставляя x==1 получаем условие (!y || z) == (w == z). Опять, выбирая поочередно y, z, w равным 1, а остальные - 0, находим, что такого набора не существует (убедитесь сами).

Так что задача решения не имеет.

Программа, которую я набросал, выглядит так -

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

bool chk(bool a[4])
{
    return bool(((!a[2])||a[3])||((!a[1])&&a[0])) == bool(a[0] == a[3]);
}

void F(int p[4])
{
    bool a[][4] =
    {
        {false,true,false,false},{true,true,false,false},  // line 1
        {false,false,false,true},                          // line 2
        // line 3
        {false,true,false,false},{false,true,false,true},{false,true,true,false},{false,true,true,true}
    };

    bool res = true;

    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]); ++i)
    {
        bool b[4];
        b[0] = a[i][p[0]];
        b[1] = a[i][p[1]];
        b[2] = a[i][p[2]];
        b[3] = a[i][p[3]];
        res = res && chk(b);
    }

    if (res)
    {
        cout << "wxyz"[p[0]] << "wxyz"[p[1]] << "wxyz"[p[2]] << "wxyz"[p[3]] << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int p[4] = { 0,1,2,3 };
    do
    {
        F(p);
    } while(next_permutation(p,p+4));

}
```

Она и сообщила, что решений нет, ну, а дальше я просто искал противоречивые условия...

Возможно, я как-то не так трактую задание - тогда поясните мне, в чем я неправ, буду думать дальше...

**Update**

С поправкой Mikhailo да, задача имеет единственное решение - `xzyw`, новый код -

```
bool chk(bool a[4])
{
    return bool(((!a[2])||a[3])||((!a[1])&&a[0])) == bool(a[0] == a[3]);
}

bool chk(int p[4], bool a[4])
{
    bool b[4];
    b[0] = a[p[0]];
    b[1] = a[p[1]];
    b[2] = a[p[2]];
    b[3] = a[p[3]];
    return chk(b);
}

void F(int p[4])
{
    bool a[][4] =
    {
        {false,true,false,false},{true,true,false,false},  // line 1
        {false,false,false,true},                          // line 2
        // line 3
        {false,true,false,false},{false,true,false,true},{false,true,true,false},{false,true,true,true}
    };

    bool res = (chk(p,a[0])||chk(p,a[1])) && chk(p,a[2]) &&
        (chk(p,a[3])||chk(p,a[4])||chk(p,a[5])||chk(p,a[6]));

    if (res)
    {
        cout << "wxyz"[p[0]] << "wxyz"[p[1]] << "wxyz"[p[2]] << "wxyz"[p[3]] << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int p[4] = { 0,1,2,3 };
    do
    {
        F(p);
    } while(next_permutation(p,p+4));

}
```

Comment: А может имеется в виду, что пустые места просто затерты, и надо, чтобы не "для всех", а "существуют такие, что"?...

Comment: @Mikhailo Похоже, именно так и есть - по крайней мере в этом варианте решение единственное. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Рабочий код, мб кому поможет

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
int x = 0, y = 0, z = 0, w = 0;
cout << "x y z w\n";
    for(x = 0; x < 2; x++)
      for(y = 0; y < 2; y++)
        for(z = 0; z < 2; z++)
          for(w = 0; w < 2; w++)
            if((((y<=z) | ((1-x) & w)) == (w == z)) == 1)
               cout << x << " " << y << " " << z << " " << w << "\n";
}
```